# Python loop arguments length and save all strings in one variable

Tags: python, loops, arguments

I'm trying to make my first Python script for a Discord Webhook, to make it short a C# script passes arguments to the Python script (the length of the arguments is variable) and need to concatenate all the arguments in one variable.

```py
import sys 
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed

argv_len = len(sys.argv)

for x in range(2, argv_len):
    message += sys.argv[x]
```

The error I get is: NameError: name 'message' is not defined

I expect all arguments to be saved in one variable named "message"

Comment: instantiate the variable first if you want to use the syntactic sugar of `+=`

Comment: `message = ''.join(sys.argv[2:])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to declare the variable outside the for loop in order to access it outside the loop after working with for loop, as variable have a lexical scope only.

```
argv_len = len(sys.argv)
message = ''
for x in range(2, argv_len):
    message += sys.argv[x]
print(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize `message` before you reference it. That is to say, python doesn't know what you're talking about because of the way the `+=` operator works. The `+=` operators [expects itself to be concatonating two already existing lists.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__iconcat__) However, without defining the empty list first, there is only one list.

Once this is implemented, your code should look something like this:

```py
import sys 
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed

argv_len = len(sys.argv)

message = []
for x in range(2, argv_len):
    message += sys.argv[x]
```

Also, an easier way to do this is [slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html). This would cut off the first two args and leave the rest in an array. (Credits to @furas for mentioning this). That could would be as follows:

```py
import sys 
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed

message = sys.argv[2:]
```

This takes the elements starting after the first two, all the way to the end of the list. (It starts *at* index 2, inclusively, and goes to the end of the list inclusively)

Comment: Are the arguments in message as you supplied them in the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Declare the variable message before you start the for loop.